# Solution to differential equation of function of two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Very simple question about differential equations, but I couldn't find anything online.

Let $f(x,z)$ be a function of two variables that satisfies:

$af+bf_x+cf_z+df_{xx}+ef_{zz}+gf_{xz}=q(x,z)$

where $q(x,z)$ is some known function, $a,b,c,d,e,g$ are constants.

How can I solve this, i.e., find an expression for $f(x,z)$ (given boundary conditions)?

Is there some reference where I can find general solution to differential equations of functions of two variables?

Comment: didn't realize those are constants.  That is a good deal easier.  Perhaps someone can you give a nice recipe for determining it's type and change variables to a known solution.

Comment: are $a,\cdots,g$ related i.e. It would be nice if $\left(\alpha\partial_x +\beta\partial_z +\gamma\right)^2f = af+\cdots gf_{zz}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the classification: parabolic, elliptic and hyperbolic PDEs?

Comment: There is not, and cannot be, a cookbook for solving partial differential equations.

Comment: I am not familiar with parabolic, elliptic and hyperbolic, I guess I should be. Googling "Introduction to PDEs" I found some useful material, it doesn't really seem to be a cookbook as there is for ODEs.